# sqldf is not working inside a user defined function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sqldf, pandasql

I am getting table from oracle database and converted that into pandas DataFrame (df).I access this dataframe into my summary function and create a new dataframe (crit_df) from it. Till here everything works fine but when I use (crit_df) to create new dataframe(new_df) then I get error as output : no such table: crit_df

Also when I try to print crit_df outside the function then it throws error as : NameError: crit_df is not defined.

So I believe crit_df is a local variable only.

P.S: When I perform all these operation without any function like, creating new_df from crit_df outside any function then everything works fine. But I need summary function to pass numerous criteria. I am using jupyter notebook for this.

Thanks in advance.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandasql import sqldf

run_qry = lambda q: sqldf(q, globals())
df = run_qry("""select * from **table**""")#getting this **table** from oracle database successfully

def summary(criteria):
 crit_df=run_qry("""select a,b,c from df where amount in """ +criteria+""" group by a""")
 print(crit_df)
 #crit_df is printed till here but cannot move to next line and throws error.
 new_df=  run_qry("""select distinct b from crit_df""")
 #error occurs here

summary("('P')")

OUTPUT: #it prints crit_df dataframe
        OperationalError : no such table crit_df
```

Comment: `globals()` will return something different within a function. Have you checked, wether its result is as desired?

Comment: Hi guidot, Yes, as you mentioned, when I print crit_df then it prints the desired result only. Thanks :)